# rendering images from local storage dynamically

Tags: react-native

i am trying to set selected avatar dynamically from local storage when user click on avatar.

```
const img1 =   '../../../assets/images/avatars/avatar1.png'
const img2 = '../../../assets/images/avatars/avatar2.png'
```

using onSelectedAvatar function i am trying to get user's selected image and set image in state.

```
 function onSelectAvatar(selectedAvatar) {
            setAvatar(selectedAvatar)
            setChangeAvtar(false)
    }
```

changeAvatar is a bool variable and if user click or select avatar then it render selected avatar and if it's false then it show uri image which comes through api

```
              {changeAvtar ?
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: avatar }}
                        style={styles.logo}
                        resizeMode="contain"
                    /> :
                    <Image
                    source={avatar}
                    resizeMode="contain"
           

 // here is the issue not able to display the avatar
                //If i select manually it displays the image - source={img1}


                        />
                    }
```

Here, I displayed the avatar option to change avatar when user click on avatar then I'm passing the selected avatar into the onSelectedAvatar function.

```
                   <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => onSelectAvatar(img1)}
                    >
                        <Image
                            source={require(img1)}
                            style={{
                                height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius:40,margin: 5
                            }}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => onSelectAvatar(img2)}
                    >
                        <Image
                            source={require(img2)}
                            style={{
                                height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius:40,margin: 5
                            }}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the definition to following

Previous

```
const img1 =   '../../../assets/images/avatars/avatar1.png'
const img2 = '../../../assets/images/avatars/avatar2.png'
```

New

```
const img1 =   require('../../../assets/images/avatars/avatar1.png')
const img2 = require('../../../assets/images/avatars/avatar2.png')
```

and remove `require` where you are calling in the `source`

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for response, 
when i added the changes as per your given solution it works but i am not able to convert selected image into base 64 to send the image to api. When i  used console.log to check image path it return integer value. @selectedAvatar